# Rust's equivalent of Python's ljust() string method

Tags: python, rust

I need to left-justify a `&str` in Rust.

In Python, I would do:

```
f"{spam}: {eggs}".ljust(curses.COLS - 1)
```

How can I do this idiomatically in Rust?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Formatting macros such as `println!`, `write!` and `format!` offer this functionality. Have a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#fillalignment and https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#width.

- `{:5}` specifies a minimum width of 5
- `{:-<5}` left-aligns to five digits and fills with `-`
- `{1:0$}`: "The value for the width can also be provided as a usize in the list of parameters by adding a postfix $, indicating that the second argument is a usize specifying the width."

Comment: How can I specify `width` as a variable?

Comment: Seems like so `println!("Hello {1:0$}!", 5, "x");`.

Comment: One more question and I'm going to accept the answer. What are 1 and 0?

Comment: `1` says: Take argument with index 1 (i.e. "x"), `0` says: take argument 0. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#positional-parameters